# Best for content management wiki with files ?

Tags: wiki

I'm looking for a best content management software which can be installed in a local machine and share the url to other network users.

Requirement:
1) Need to add huge pages - more than 100 or 1000 with clear navigation
2) Need to provide links in the page for the files uploaded

Tried media wiki but it doesn't seems to be that great or easy to modify

Could someone suggest me a best software?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following and configured media wiki easily without any hassles

Downloaded the following:

1. EasyPHP-12.0_with_PHP-5.4.4-setup
2. mediawiki-1.19.1 (ex: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download)
3. MySQL Database above 5

Installation Of EasyPHP
   1. Click EasyPHP-12.0_with_PHP-5.4.4-setup.exe
   2. English
   3. Next
   4. I accept the agreement
   5. Next
   6. Select the folder to install
   7. Next
   8. Install
   9. Lauch PHP

Install MySQL, create user and give permissions for the users.

Installing MediaWiki:

1. Extract the downloaded media wiki package "mediawiki-1.19.1" to a folder.
     copy the medi wiki extracted folder into www folder
    (Ex: D:\EasyPHP-12.0\www)
2. go to your browser and see your local site
3. You can see a new link "mediawiki-1.19.1" under Portable files and click the same
4. It goes to setup wiki
5. your language and wiki language - english
6. continue
7. continue
8. Database type - MySQL
9. database name - any name

   1. Database password
   2. Next
   3. Name Of the Wiki - > OperativeOne
   4. continue
   5. Install -> continue
   6. continue
   7. copy the LocalSettings.php to the mediawiki folder
      ex: D:\EasyPHP-12.0\www\mediawiki-1.19.1

For Upload File Permission or Enable File Upload:
    Edit the LocalSettings.php in ex: D:\EasyPHP-12.0\www\mediawiki-1.19.1
    $wgEnableUploads  = true;

To support multiple file types you need to add the extension in the LocalSettings.php
$wgFileExtensions = array('pdf','png','jpg','jpeg','ogg','doc','xls','ppt','mp3','sxc','nse','opt', 'zip', 'doc', 'ppt', 'pdf','jar', 'png', 'txt','opt','odp','otp','.xls','.xlsx');

Increase the upload file size limit, add like the below
Easy Php task bar icon -> Right Click -> Administration -> PHP -> Change
     -> Configuration File (Modify) -> upload max filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M

To make the wiki just read only
$wgReadOnly = 'Only Read Only Access';

To make no one should create a new account
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;

To make the visitor restricted
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit']             = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createpage']       = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createtalk']       = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['writeapi']         = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read']             = true;

Link for Reference:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights#Default_rights
http://www.howtogeek.com/67717/how-to-setup-your-own-powerful-wiki-on-your-windows-pc/